# Have any pseudo-anglicisms become proper English words?

Tags: loanwords, neologisms

There are plenty of [pseudo-anglicisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-anglicism) in other languages around the world: *Handy, Pullunder, Showmaster* and *Beamer*¹ in German. These words, though borrowed from English, are used differently from their usual English meanings. Have any pseudo-anglicisms later become common English words?

<sup>¹ I’m mentioning Beamer (German word for projector) especially as there is a popular package for the LaTeX typesetting system that helps in creating projection slide; such uses could potentially spread a pseudo-anglicism.</sup>

Comment: It's doubtful that Beamer for a piece of software will ever catch on in the US since BMW's have already been nicknamed that phonetically- spelled either Beemer or Bimmer depending on whether it's a motorcycle or a car you're talking about; but pronounced the same either way.  Are you talking about words like *croissant*?

Comment: Have you observed this among anglophones in Germany? Perhaps you are thinning of a geographic or cultural context in which English overlaps with other languages. This occurs frequently with Japanese pop culture: Pokémon is a Japanese English contraction and abbreviation for pocket monster, karaoke is a portmanteau of kara (open) and orchestra; and anime is either derived from French image animé or English animation. Of course all these words are broadly used in English. Is that what you're getting at?

Comment: Via LaTeX, "beamer" has spread into popular use in the hard sciences.

Comment: This is an interesting question, now that I know what a pseudo-anglicism is. I added a link and brief definition to the question to help other readers.

Comment: Would you count American/former British Commonwealth words which have taken on new meanings and been absorbed back into BrEng?  I'm sure there must be 17th century words which emigrated with settlers, developed new meanings, and have been accepted back as what Brits would call 'Americanisms'.

Comment: @commonhare: Can you prove that somehow?

Comment: No, not really.  But here's an interesting one:  the "oke" part of karaoke comes from "orche"stra.  (The "kara" 空 means "empty".)  So that's sort of English --> Japanese --> English.  (Or Greek --> Latin --> English --> Japanese --> English, to be exhaustive.)

Comment: @commonhare Bravo! there's plenty of research behind that. Wish you didn't just say "No, not really." Do try.

Comment: I thought Germans use the word the word *"pullover"*, not pullunder. (For a sweater, right?)

Comment: @KristinaLopez Pullover and Pullunder are different things; think the the former have sleeves and the latter not. See http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullunder and http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullover

Comment: @JoachimBreitner thanks, I learned something new today! :-)

Comment: How about this Filipinisms: jeepney, plastic (i.e. fake)... I can only think of 2 for now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Anglicism):  "Pseudo-anglicisms are related to false friends [hyperlinked] or false cognates [hyperlinked]. Many speakers of a language which employs pseudo-anglicisms believe that the relevant words are genuine anglicisms and can be used in English, which may cause misunderstandings.  When many English words are incorporated into many languages, language enthusiasts and purists often look down on this phenomenon, terming it (depending on the importing language) Denglisch, Franglais or similar neologisms."

From Lloyd James' website (http://www.lloydbingham.co.uk/2013/02/top-5-pseudo-anglicisms-in-german.html) come the following pseudo-anglicisms:

> downloader, streetworker, talkmaster, know-how, wellness, and beamer.

Of interest to readers of EL&U:

> **Wellness**:  "Germans will associate this word with being pampered at a Wellness-Hotel, perhaps in the secluded mountains of Austria where one can enjoy the utmost tranquility and relaxation. In English, we could probably just call this a spa."
>   **Streetworker**:  "The meaning of streetworker [the "real" English word being streetwalker!]is more innocent in German [than English], referring to a social worker rather than a lady who was the object of the 1978 single Roxanne by The Police."

In answer to your question, I am familiar with only one anglicism, and that is the Japanese/English term **Walkman**, which was a popular medium of portable music decades ago that featured a pint-size combination AM/FM radio and cassette player--with headphones (or ear-buds), of course.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm most familiar with the Japanese pseudo-Anglicisms called [wasei-eigo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasei-eigo). There are a few examples in the Wikipedia article that I would recognize as reasonable English, but I don't think it's because they were loaned back into English. Walkman is a good example, though, which did start out as wasei-eigo and caught on here better than the English-market name “Soundabout.”

Comment: I think Walkman is different, because it started out as a trademark for portable audio cassette players by Sony. Similar to "Xerox" it was [genericized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_trademark).

Comment: Yes, and it's surprising how many genericisms there are!  Personally, I prefer to use "photocopy" rather than "Xerox," "bandage" rather than "Band-Aid," and "ibuprofen" and "acetaminophen" rather than "Motrin" and "Tylenol."  It's just a "thing" of mine.  Sorry I couldn't give you more examples of pseudo-anglicisms.  Perhaps other EL&Uers will pipe in with examples.

Comment: If walkman is now the common English word for a portable cassette player while originally coined in a different Languge, then for me, it’d count.

Comment: Was *walkman* a word or even *walk-man* a set phrase in English, before Sony?

Comment: @Kris OED says *Walkman* was coined following the pattern of *pressman* and that the Walkman was first produced in 1977 and launched in 1979. Their first citation is from the NYT in 1980 (mentioning a price tag of $200!) so it looks like the answer to your comment is No.

Answer (score 2):

*anime*

The Japanese borrowed the English word *animation*, abbreviated it to *anime* and used it to refer animated movies and videos.

The English then took the word *anime* back, and used it to refer specifically to Japanese animated movies and videos.